# Javascript string replace with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to replace `1` with `2` using a regex? The values in the first brackets will always be whole numbers. I started doing this using `str.split('[')` and realised that's not the best way.

EDIT - the value in the first brackets can be any whole number. This string is basically the name attribute of a form field in a big dynamic form. The form is made up of fields in rows and the number in the first brackets indicated the row. A new line of fields is added by cloning the last row but the row index needs to be updated in the name attribute.

```
value[1][some_string]
```

Comment: Your actual string is `"value[1][some_string]"`? And you want to make change it to `"value[2][some_string]"`? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: `.replace("1", "2")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(value)\[(\d+)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `$1[<any number>`

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/56

```
var re = /(value)\[(\d+)/gm;
var str = 'value[1][some_string]';
var subst = '$1[2';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: line three should be more like `var subst = '$1[2';`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @devnull69 it can be anything

Comment: except that it was '\1' before :-) and the OP specifically wanted to replace the content of the first brackets with `2`

Answer (score 0):

better use replace...

This wil replace the first match:

```
str.replace("1","2");
```

This wil replace all `1` with `2`.

```
var patt = new RegExp("1", "g");
str.replace(patt, "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your updated question, try:

```
function inc_cnt(s){return Number(s)+1;}
elm.name=elm.name.replace(/\d+(?=\]\[)/, inc_cnt);
```

<sup>* (assuming `elm` is your cloned element)</sup>

This regex will match *the first occurrence of:* any digits *followed by* `][`
(for example it will only match `26` in `value[26][some_val_42][foo_bar]`).

This match then gets passed to function `inc_cnt` that accepts string representing decimal number, converts it to a number and adds 1 to it, returning resulting number to the replace method
(*effectively auto-incrementing your counter*).

Note, alternatively the payload of `inc_cnt` could be changed to `return parseInt(s, 10)+1` OR you could count on the coercing feature and do `return +s+1`.

Depending on your coding-style you could re-factor that to:

```
elm.name=elm.name.replace(/\d+(?=\]\[)/, function(s){return +s+1});
```

Also, note that *only*: `<a>`, `<applet>`, `<button>`, `<form>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<map>`, `<meta>`, `<object>`, `<param>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` support direct getting/setting of the name *attribute* (via `elm.name`).
Other elements require `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` *methods*.

Hope this helps!